# sql if not exists () insert not working

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, select, exists

This is my query:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   teovecerdi 
               WHERE  LocationName = 'Frankfurt' 
               AND    StartDate = '14/02/2015' 
               AND    EndDate = '17/02/2015' 
               AND    Price = '2700') 
INSERT INTO teovecerdi(LocationName, StartDate, EndDate, Price)
VALUES(?,?,?,?)
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with it? I've also tried with BEGIN and END and it still gives me an error.

EDIT: I handle the parameters correctly.

Comment: you may want to just create a unique index on those fields, and then do `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Price=Price` or `INSERT IGNORE ...`

Comment: Some guidance: https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/

Comment: Are the values in the `NOT EXISTS` query the same as the values you're trying to insert? Then you could use `INSERT IGNORE` if they include a unique index of the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an `IF` statement in a query, it can only be used in a stored procedure.

If you want to do a conditional `INSERT`, you can use a `SELECT` query that only returns a row when the condition is met.

```
INSERT INTO teovecerdi(LocationName, StartDate, EndDate, Price)
SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
    FROM   teovecerdi 
    WHERE  LocationName = 'Frankfurt' 
    AND    StartDate = '14/02/2015' 
    AND    EndDate = '17/02/2015' 
    AND    Price = '2700')
```

Comment: Nice, interesting approach! I guess `DUAL` is some kind of dummy table?

Comment: Yes, that's what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use MySQL's procedural syntax (including `IF`'s like that, as well as iterating constructs, etc...) in queries or scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest a different approach.  My guess is that you want `LocationName, StartDate, EndDate, Price` to be unique.  So, let the database do the work for you:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_teovecerdi_4 on teovecerdi(LocationName, StartDate, EndDate, Price);
```

Then just be careful to "ignore" errors when you do an insert.  My preferred method is:

```
INSERT INTO teovecerdi (LocationName, StartDate, EndDate, Price)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE LocationName = VALUES(LocationName);
```

The `ON DUPLICATE KEY` does nothing except absorb the error, when you attempt to insert a duplicate.